# Writing a Zero Byte File Before Total File Is Written to the Mounted Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

I have a mounted bucket using gcsfuse version 0.28.  I have a file, say 200MB or greater that I am copying over to the mounted directory/bucket.  GCSFUSE first writes a zero byte file, removes it in the target directory, and then writes the full file to the directory.

When the receiving application is listening for messages on this mounted bucket, they receive the zero byte message and not the fully written file.

My question is this:  if upgrading to gcsfuse 0.31, will this handle this functionality and resolve this issue or do I need to manually fix this myself and control how the app listens to and processes the incoming data on the target mounted bucket?

Answer (score 0):

You should try first to update to the latest version and see if the issue still persist.

In the case it actually persist after upgrading the version, yes you should try to change the code and the way you control the app and how it listens. You could try adding some logic in order to skip the file if it detects it with 0 Mb and go for the ones with >= than 1 Mb but I am not sure if this is good in the long run.

Also, I would suggest you to post in the [Issues](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues) page for GCSFuse so the team is aware of this kind of issue.